# Static method in trait dynamic dispatch

Tags: rust

Trying to get dynamic dispatch working in a trait static method but get a type must be known error.

I'm trying to achieve something like

- F#
  https://github.com/Thorium/SimpleCQRS-FSharp/blob/master/CommandSide/Domain.fs
- C#
  https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/master/SimpleCQRS/Domain.cs..

Is the only way to make the trait generic?

```
pub struct Aggregate<T: AggregateRoot>
{
    pub id: Uuid,
    agg: T,
    changes:  Vec<Box<Any>>
}

impl <T :AggregateRoot > Aggregate<T>
{
    fn GetUncomittedChanges(&self) -> Vec<Box<Any>> { self.changes}
    fn MarkChangesAsCommitted(&self)  { self.changes.drain(..);}
}


trait AggregateRoot
{
    fn new2() -> Self;  //should be private
    fn new(id: Uuid) -> Self;

    fn LoadsFromHistory(changes : Vec<Box<Any>> ) -> Self
         where Self: Sized
    {
        let newAgg  = AggregateRoot::new2 ();
        changes.iter().map( |e| newAgg.Apply(e) );
        newAgg.MarkChangesAsCommitted();
        newAgg
    }

    fn Apply<U: Any>(&self, arg: U) ;
    fn GetId(&self) -> Uuid;
}
```

currently trying  but gives 2 params expected 1 supplied.

Comment: The code as presented has problems and does not have an error as described. Instead, after making the code compile, the errors I get are "the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Self`" and "no method named `map`". Please create an [MCVE](/help/mcve), ideally one that compiles on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/).

Comment: The where clause gets you to that error but it doesn't look right second error is fixed with iter() . FIrst error is how do you do it .. I don't know what to do to get it to compile.   This is my current attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with issues in how you asked the question, in the hopes that you will be able to ask better questions in the future. The complete error you are getting is:

```
<anon>:27:37: 27:52 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
<anon>:27             changes.iter().map( |e| newAgg.Apply(e) );
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Note that the compiler error message shows you exactly which bit of code is at fault. It's useful to include that error when asking a question.

You've also included extraneous detail. For example, `GetUncomittedChanges`, `id` and `GetId` are all unused in your example. When solving a problem, you should produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve). This helps you understand the problem better and also allows people helping you to look at less code which usually results in faster turnaround.

---

Your code has a number of problems, but let's start at the first error:

```
let newAgg  = AggregateRoot::new2 ();
```

This says "for any possible `AggregateRoot`, create a new one". Many concrete types can implement a trait (which is the point of traits), but the compiler needs to know how much space to allocate for a given instance. There might be a struct that takes 1 byte or 200 bytes; how much space needs to be allocated on the stack in *this* case?

To progress, you can use `Self::new2` instead. That means to create a new instance **of the current implementor**.

The next error is

```
<anon>:20:16: 20:40 error: no method named `MarkChangesAsCommitted` found for type `Self` in the current scope
<anon>:20         newAgg.MarkChangesAsCommitted();
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You are calling a method on a concrete type from a trait implementation; this simply doesn't make any sense. What would happen if a `bool` implements this trait? It doesn't have a `MarkChangesAsCommitted` method. I don't know what you intended in this case, so I'll just delete it.

Now you get this error:

```
<anon>:19:9: 19:16 error: `changes` does not live long enough
<anon>:19         changes.iter().map( |e| newAgg.Apply(e) );
                  ^~~~~~~

note: reference must be valid for the static lifetime...
<anon>:17:5: 21:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the scope of parameters for function at 17:4
```

That's because your method `Apply` expects to be given a type that implements `Any`. However, you are passing a `&Box<Any>`. `Any` has a lifetime bound of `'static`, and that reference is not static. A straightforward change is to accept a reference to a type that implements `Any`:

```
fn Apply<U: Any>(&self, arg: &U);
```

---

Now that the code compiles, there's a number of stylistic issues to fix:

1. no space before `:`
2. no space after `>`
3. no space before `(`
4. no space inside `()`
5. `map` should not be used for side effects
6. function and variable names are `camel_case`
7. most of the time, accept a `&[T]` instead of a `Vec<T>` as a function argument.
8. use "Egyptian" braces, except when you are using a `where` clause.

All together, your code looks like:

```
use std::any::Any;

struct Aggregate<T: AggregateRoot> {
    agg: T,
    changes: Vec<Box<Any>>
}

impl<T: AggregateRoot> Aggregate<T> {
    fn mark_changes_as_committed(&self) { }
}

trait AggregateRoot {
    fn new() -> Self;

    fn load_from_history(changes: &[Box<Any>]) -> Self
         where Self: Sized
    {
        let new_agg = Self::new();
        for change in changes { new_agg.apply(change) }
        new_agg
    }

    fn apply<U: Any>(&self, arg: &U);
}

fn main() {}
```

---

> Is there a way to constrain the concrete types of the `AggregateRoot` to `Aggregates` so `mark_changes` can be called?

Not that I'm aware of. It sounds like you want to move `mark_changes` to the trait and force all implementors of the trait to implement it:

```
trait AggregateRoot {
    fn load_from_history(changes: &[Box<Any>]) -> Self
         where Self: Sized
    {
        let new_agg = Self::new();
        for change in changes { new_agg.apply(change) }
        new_agg.mark_changes_as_committed();
        new_agg
    }

    fn mark_changes_as_committed(&self);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to constrain the concrete types of the Aggregateroot  to Aggregates so mark changes can be called ? The apply was what i was looking for.. When learning a new language you try many things. This says "for any possible AggregateRoot, create a new one".    The purpose of this is so external objects can create the concrete implementation and populate it via events ( normally a repository)  , which the concrete impl will handle..   The caller can mark it as complete but it leads to bad bugs if not done.

Comment: @user1496062 I answered your question inline. I wasn't clear if there were more question hidden in your comment :-)

Comment: Thanks.   markchanges relates specifically to the data , it clears the underlying collection ..  You can see from the C# / F# examples what I'm trying to do. As they have some concrete implementations which I haven't got to yet.  Note all impl will use the struct Aggregate and extend it  , they are very closely linked.